# Один статический объект на два процесса

Tags: java

Как создать один статический объект на два процесса?

Есть программа для раздачи образов дисков (сервер для Android приложения). Локальная часть добавления файлов — один модуль, сервлеты в контейнере *Tomcat* для раздачи образов — второй, а БД — третий. И так получается, что нереально кешировать данные, не имея общего объекта БД

Если использовать класс со статической переменной, вполне логично, эта переменная будет единственной только в своем процессе, то есть два объекта на два процесса.

---

Как сделать так, чтобы у двух процессов был лишь один статический объект на двоих?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос: Если одна прога запущена из командной строки, а вторая это сервлет живущий в контейнере Tomcat - то это два разных JVM... Вы хотите получить один объект на 2 разных экземпляра JVM?

Comment: @Barmaley, ну... Видимо, да.

Comment: Ну тогда версия @AndrewBystrov - самое то

Comment: Вангую XY problem. Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @Etki, есть программа для раздачи образов дисков (сервер для Android приложения). Локальная часть добавления файлов — один модуль, сервлеты для раздачи образов — второй, а БД — третий. И так получается, что нереально кешировать данные, не имея общего объекта БД.

Comment: Если вы хотите шарить поведение в первую очередь - то сервлет может по любому RPC (RMI хотя бы) ходить в приложение, запущенное из командной строки. Если речь о данных - можно взять какой-нибудь hazelcast.

Comment: Сделайте процесс запускаемый из командной строки просто клиентом к сервлету. Т.е. всю работу выполняет сервлет, а CLI просто интерфейс к нему.

Comment: Или сервлет и приложение могут быть клиентами к третьей сущности (назовем ее "сервер"), которая непосредственно займетсяя бизнес-логикой.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, поздно... Я уже написал и понял, что упустил разделение программы на два процесса. Так что писать уже все на сервлетах — лень, да и не хочу (вообще, я только с Android'ом дружу, но никто не хотел браться, вот я и начал делать..., там вообще все на Google Guice, Swing и SQLite :D).

Comment: @Nofate, ну... Если я Вас правильно понял, третья сущность и есть третий модуль. Только вот этот модуль — имеется в разных объектах.

Comment: @Nofate, RPC, RMI не то, а hazelcast — что-то страшное...

Comment: Лень - это так себе аргумент в техническом вопросе. Чем не подходит RPC? Сделаете консольный клиент на Retrofit, будете в сервлет ходить.

Comment: @bukashka101 никогда не поздно сделать более удобный и расширяемый дизайн. Technical debt все равно придется платить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50784/discussion-between-bukashka101-and-nofate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо хранить этот объект где-то за пределеами ваших процессов. Хорошим примером будет использовать shared memory ( вроде бы хорошая [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/148139/) по использованию)

В самом примитивном случае - сохраняйте в файл состояние объекта ( посредством сериализации), забирайте его оттуда, и снова кладите в этот файл.